# How to add text on image using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I am **adding text on image** but not woking? I have one more question. If I use class row image is taking lot of space vertically how to solve it? I mean can I use **specific height for image in Bootstrap**?

```css
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="pic4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    <div class="text-center bg-text inner">
      <h1> acknowledge Nature! </h1>
      <p>Nature is the most important thing in the life which is alive.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use position absolute, you have to specify which container to sort by. there's no top 20. you can use PX or%. In addition, if you do not use position relative in any container, the content will sort itself by body.

I have taken images and texts into a single container. and I applied position relative to the container that covers them. The text will then sort itself in this container. I set the values to mean the text, but of course you can change it.

2.to answer your question, yes you can use. Like (w-100, h-75). But since you have changed the size of the image after you have done this, you need to adjust it again for each size to appear responsive. (media queries). If you want to keep the picture the same size at all times, I suggest you look for ***aspect-ratio-container***.

```css
.img-text-container {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="img-text-container">
    <img src="https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    <div class="text-center bg-text inner">
      <h1> acknowledge Nature! </h1>
      <p>Nature is the most important thing in the life which is alive.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even class is text-center, we need to top:  50% and left: 50% ?

Comment: Width is 100% but not covering 100% from left through right?

Comment: 1- text-center required to center the text in the container. I used 50% 50% center to the Container.

Comment: 2- It's not really necessary, it already belongs to the img-fluid class, you may not use it.

Comment: Does image needs specific height and width ? Because my image is covering more height  as need to scroll it. I don't know why? And I don't want that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: My image is so big ( on screen )that I need to scroll it.

Comment: of course you can adjust your picture. You can also use object-fit:"cover" to ensure that your image is properly proportioned in different sizes. No matter what size your picture is. The writing will always be in the middle. It is also possible to intervene in the container covering the text and adjust its size.

Comment: Do I need to crop image in specific height and width ? But I can see you use link for image.

Comment: Looks like you're pretty new. :) no problem. I used it as a link because I can not see a picture in your local store. That's how I used it to set an example for you. You guys use the picture from your local store.

Comment: Yes I am still leaning. I know that local image or link can be use